# Java 1.6 installation

Tags: software-installation, java

I tried to install Java 6 as follows:

```
chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin 
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv jdk1.6.0_45 /usr/lib/jvm
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
ls -la /etc/alternatives/java*
```

Afterwards I checked with `java -version`, but it's giving the below error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM  
Unable to load native library: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file:   
 No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm actually answering your question, but https://sdkman.io/ is a tool which saved me lot of hassle installing different versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need Java 6 try to build libnsl from source. Guide [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/libnsl.html). I simply would recommend to install Java 8 and compile with `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java) question for more info how to compile for older versions of Java. (Don't use Java 9 or newer as not all programs from java 8 and older will run there.)